# Django Static Setup

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I've looked through countless answers and questions trying to find a single definitive guide or way to do this, but it seems that everyone has a different way. Can someone please just explain to me how to serve static files in templates?

Assuming I've just created a brand new project with Django 1.4, what all do I need to do to be able to render images? Where should I put the media and static folders?

Comment: Not helpful but I feel your pain.  I feel like it should be simple, but there must be some fundamental gap in basic understanding that I don't get.  It's not clear to me what the diff between media and static are, other than user-uploaded vs something else.

Comment: @user798719  Actually I figured it out, and it is quite simple once you get it down the first time.

STATIC_ROOT is the directory all of your static files get collected in.
STATIC_URL is the url the static files will be available at (eg <img src="/(insert STATIC_URL here)/img.png"> )
MEDIA_ROOT is the path to the directory where all user upload files will go

Comment: @user798719
STATIC_ROOT is the directory all of your static files get collected in.
STATIC_URL is the url the static files will be available at (eg <img src="/(insert STATIC_URL here)/img.png"> )
MEDIA_ROOT is the path to the directory where all user upload files will go
MEDIA_URL is the same as STATIC_URL, just the reference to the uri that the files will be available on
STATICFILES_DIRS is a tuple with paths of where all the files will be stored before collected for deployment HOWEVER you cannot have STATIC_ROOT in STATICFILES_DIR or it will throw an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put your static files into `<app>/static` or add an absolute path to `STATICFILES_DIRS`
2. Configure your web server (you should not serve static files with Django) to serve files in `STATIC_ROOT`
3. Point `STATIC_URL` to the base URL the web server serves
4. Run `./manage.py collectstatic`
5. Be sure to use `RequestContext` in your render calls and `{{ STATIC_URL }}` to prefix paths
6. Coffee and pat yourself on the back

A little bit more about running a web server in front of Django. Django is practically an application server. It has not been designed to be any good in serving static files. That is why it actively refuses to do that when `DEBUG=False`. Also, the Django development server should not be used for production. This means that there should be something in front of Django at all times. It may be a WSGI server such as gunicorn or a 'real' web server such as nginx or Apache.

If you are running a reverse proxy (such as nginx or Apache) you can bind `/static` to a path in the filesystem and the rest of the traffic to pass through to Django. That means your `STATIC_URL` can be a relative path. Otherwise you will need to use an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

The created project should have a static folder. Put all resources (images, ...) in there.
Then, in your HTML template, you can reference STATIC_ROOT and add the resource path (relative to the static folder)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation:

How to manage static files:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/

Static Files in general:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

If you are planning to to deploy in a production type setting then you should read the section here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-production

Generally you put our static and media folders outside of the django project app

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why put static files outside of the app?

Comment: Rendering HTML and talking with database are a completely separate set of problems from serving files. Django itself is not trying to be a perfect web server, quite the contrary: it is a WSGI application that requires a front end of one type or another. The `./manage.py runserver` is designed for development only.

Answer (score 0):

- Define your STATICFILES_DIRS, STATIC, and MEDIA path in the settings.
- Create staticfiles folder beside your templates folder, urls.py, settings.py, etc...
- You don't have to create media folder because it will automatically created when you upload images.
- In your urlconf put this one:

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
  from django.conf.urls.static import static

  admin.autodiscover()

  urlpatterns = patterns('',
      .............
  ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
  ```
- In templates:

  ```
  {% load static %}
  <img src="{% static 'images.png' %}">
  <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}images.png">
  ```

Comment: This will work, however Django will be serving the files which is discouraged by the documentation.

Comment: Django 1.4 is using the {% load static %}. Django 1.5 is using the {% load static from staticfiles %}. If you want to use the old one {{STATIC_URL}} it's your option

Comment: That made the the image from the media folder work, but still no luck with the static folder.

Comment: static folder must be staticfiles folder. Don't override the default static folder for django collecstatic